# (Probably) freeze in verifySessionCookie in firebase authentication

Tags: c#, node.js, firebase

I verified the sessionCookie with code like this.

```
node.js
export const sign = functions_address.https.onCall(
  (data,conext) =>{
      // get a sessionCookie
      const sessionCookieString = data.cookies;
      const payload_j = data.payload;
      
      log(sessionCookieString);
      admin.auth().verifySessionCookie(sessionCookieString, true).then((decodeclaims) =>{
        
          //Action

      }).catch ((error) => {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("Unauthenticated", "SessionCookie Failed.");
      });
```

However, it freezes without even displaying the log(sessionCookieString).
What causes the freeze?

From C#, we call it this way.

I have already verified that the contents are not empty.

```
var d_payload = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        d_payload["cookies"] = Cookie;
        d_payload["payload"] = payload;
await setconst.func.GetHttpsCallable("sign").CallAsync(d_payload).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            {
                string jsonString = (string)task.Result.Data;
                Dictionary<string, string> jsonData = JsonUtility.FromJson<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);

                j_signedpayload = jsonData["payload"];

                Debug.Log("payload: " + j_signedpayload);
            }
        else
            {
                result = "Auth Error";
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just an ordinary mistake. Elsewhere in the original program,

```
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(Cookie)){
```

But I needed to write

```
if(!string.isNullOrEmpty(Cookie)){
```